# In React, how to track the content width exceeds parent container width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a container with a maximum width 450px. It's a single-line container with property `white-space` set `nowrap`.

What I need to do is to add children elements (those can be simple span or some custom react components) until the content exceeds maximum width. When the content exceeds maximum width, the last child should not be added to the container, but the text "... +n items" should appear.

I'm not satisfied with the `overflow: hidden` because it just cuts off overflowed text. I guess I have to iterate over the items checking if existing content width plus new item's width exceeds container width.. But it seems for me pretty complicated to realize :(

Any help would be appreciated

I tried creating elements through `createElement` getting their width and calculating things. But I have no idea how to get elements width before render.